changes on several Series by vba in Excel Chart.Series.Format.Line.Weight do not reliably lead to change in Chart
I tried to emulate a sankey chart with a line chart in excel 2021. (for having direct access to the Charts events i use a chart as Chartsheet) I have 36 lines within this chart and i use the Series.format.line.weight property for changing the weight for each line. The line weight is taken by code from a range in a Worksheet. All my code works fine but if i change the values in the range for the line.weight by looping through, the changes don't reliable take effect on the properties of the chart
part of my code:
for i = 1 to 36   
      myChart.Format.Line.Weight = theLineWeight(i)
' theLineWeight(i) reads the i.th value from a range containing the values for the weights
next i

this code sometimes works and sometimes not. I can't figure out, on what conditions the code has effect and on what not...
I tried to refresh the Chart by myChart.refresh after each property change, i also tried if there is an effect if i deselect the Chart by activating another sheet and selecting a range within. Another try was changing the charts visibilty. All tries didn't really effect. What can i do?

Sorry my code snippet contains mistakes, because i tried to reduce it.
But the problem is real. let me please give the corrected code:
For i = 1 To 36
  myChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = theLineWeight(i)
Next i

'theLineWeight(i) reads the Value from a range


Please don't post code as comment - just edit your question and correct the code thre.

@FunThomas: Thank you for your reply! Sorry, it's my first question here. I didn't know, that i can change the code afterwards. And i don't how to add code to my query in the correct way. Next time i try better ;-) Even i didn't find another way to reply to comment as i do now

Don't worry. For formatting, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting If you found the answer yourself, you can create an answer to your question and accept it (I guess you have to wait a while for that).

The explanation for the seemingly arbitrary behavior when trying to change the line weight was that some of the lines were dynamically switched to invisible. This was part of my functionality of my Sankey chart. The line weight cannot be changed as long as they are invisible. For changing line properties like weight, you must first switch on the visibility of the line:
  For i = 1 To 36
    With myChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Line
      .Visible = True
      .Weight = LineWeight(i)
    End With
  Next i

@FunThomas: Dankeschön!
